# Is there any difference, whether a struct declared in the 'extern "C"' block or not?

Tags: c++, c

Let's say, I have the header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct S
{
  int i;
  double d;
  // etc
};

// Or start the 'extern "C"' block here?..

void f(A* a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

It should be used by C/C++ sources.

My question is: if I carry the `struct A` declaration out of the `extern "C"`, whether this code will be compatible with a library which was built **with** the `struct A` declared as `extern "C"`?

That is, we built a library with the header as it is presented above, then we moved the `extern "C"` to the position marked by the corresponding comment line and, finally, we are trying to build a C++ application using the resulting header.

If all of this will be successful? In other words, if the `extern "C"` influence on a struct declaration?

Whether it depends what language (C/C++) the library is written on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern` by itself declares external linkage, which is a default state for C++ functions.

Specification "C" gives C language linkage.

***Only function names and variable names with external linkage have a language linkage, classes and class members are not affected.*** `struct` declaration is a class.  If that file meant to be used with C code, there might be problem that older C standard do not support declaration in that format.

Specification "C" makes name conventions of externally linked entities compatible with said language, even while compatibility is implementation-dependent. E.g. for gcc your function would have C++ mangled name `_Z3fooP1A`, but with C it might be just `_foo`.